# Convert System.Drawing.Image to format(.jpeg .gif) whitout saving

Tags: c#

I need to convert a  System.Drawing.Image object to gif whitout saving it to a file(that means i can't use  the save function). (bitearray or base64) sow i can send it to a web service.  the code is on a server and i don't have write permisssion on it. c# code.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid questtion, if i would have been a little more attentive i would have seen the overrloaded methods. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to save it *somewhere*. You could use a [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx), and use one of the [Save overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142147.aspx) that accepts a stream.